# もんじゃない translation attempt

Tags: grammar, translation

I'm reading a book, and the antagonist was released from prison early because he bribed the district prosecutioner.

The main character says:
野郎。。。　法なんてあってねーようなもんじゃねーか

This is my translation:
Bastard... It's like there is no law (lacking in lawfulness?)

But I'm not sure how もんじゃない functions here. I know もんだ/です can function as giving a reason for something. Is もんじゃない used similarly but ない is used because it is a negative verb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your translation attempt is spot-on.

This もん is a simple noun, "thing". [あってないようなもの](https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AA%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE) is a set phrase that means "a thing that exists but is like nonexistent," or "a thing that's virtually nonexistent". It's commonly used to describe how something is useless or meaningless.